# Nodejs, how to view jsdom in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

How can I view the html in the in the browser? Nothing shows on the localhost:3000.

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><body><p id="main">My First JSDOM!</p></body>`,
  {
    url: "http://localhost:3000/",
    contentType: "text/html",
    pretendToBeVisual: true,
  }
);
```

Comment: What do you want to happen? You want to create the JSDom and then inject it into the DOM? Why not do it directly in the real DOM?

Comment: I want to create html elements in nodejs (if possible) and put them in a html file.

Answer (score 3):

From the comment I gather you want to manipulate the DOM in JSDOM in node and then (maybe) write an html file (or return it in a response)

For that use `serialize()`

https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#serializing-the-document-with-serialize

So with your example:

```js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><body><p id="main">My First JSDOM!</p></body>`,
  {
    url: "http://localhost:3000/",
    contentType: "text/html",
    pretendToBeVisual: true,
  }
);

console.log(dom.serialize());
```

JSDom will give you a string for all your HTML.
You can then use [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) to create a server that may return that HTML or you use the string to write an HTML file to disk.

```js
const express = require('express');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><body><p id="main">My First JSDOM!</p></body>`,
  {
    url: "http://localhost:3000/",
    contentType: "text/html",
    pretendToBeVisual: true,
  }
);

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(dom.serialize());
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening at http://localhost:8080');
});
```

Comment: But how can I view it on my localhost as an html file? And doesn't nodejs wants views folder with html file?

Comment: You miss-understand what JSDom does and how Node works in general. JSDom will give you a string for all your HTML. You can then use node with [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) to create a server that may return that HTML or you use the string to write an HTML file to disk.

Comment: I updated the answer but I think we are now a bit too far away from the question and too broad in general. Maybe create a new question for the express part.

Comment: Perfect answer. Exactly what i was looking for!\

Comment: nice answer thanks